# RecyclerView with the design side of xml

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I use RecyclerView in my XML, I have a "parsing error" in the design part of the XML :
[image: graphical editor]

This is my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the Gradle I compile these libs :

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
```

And this is the SDK I use :

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 23
```

This is what I have in my "parsing error" :

```
Parsing error
ActiveTool: com.intellij.designer.designSurface.tools.SelectionTool@6218ba18
SDK: Android API 23 - API 23
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadModelBuilder.updateHierarchy(RadModelBuilder.java:329)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadModelBuilder.updateHierarchy(RadModelBuilder.java:346)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadModelBuilder.updateHierarchy(RadModelBuilder.java:203)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadModelBuilder.build(RadModelBuilder.java:169)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadModelBuilder.update(RadModelBuilder.java:85)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$4.consume(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:327)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$4.consume(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:287)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7$2.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:553)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:337)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:321)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:154)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.model.PropertyParser.load(PropertyParser.java:93)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.model.RadModelBuilder.updateHierarchy(RadModelBuilder.java:326)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: I think you should add support lib to in build.gradle

Comment: I use that lib : compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'

Comment: add compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0' and then try to clean the project and build.

Comment: I use this lib too : compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add these lines too.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

**Or**

try to restart the studio.. sometimes studio creates problem.

Comment: can you try to restart the studio?